# Updating UI from TimerTask

Tags: android, user-interface, gps, handler, timertask

I am implementing an application that get the location data in certain intervals of time and checks the location got is the destination. If current location is the destination I want to Toast or update a TextField. I used TimerTask for this. But it is not giving me the correct output. While I searched I saw that TimerTask cannot handle changes in the UI. Is there any way to solve my problem?
I want to check in certain intervals and want to update UI

Comment: see this [runOnUiThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement LocationListener instead of using TimerTask

Answer (score 3):

Just use `runOnUiThread()`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(yourContext, "Data: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: If the userlocks screen, what happens to the TimerTask?

Comment: Will still run. Stop and resume it in onpause and onresume

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `handler` to notify the ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html